# How to work with nested if statements

Tags: wp7test

I have a very big excel sheet that holds many information such as dates, item number, description, etc. I am trying to filter out a few things with if statements but i am like filtering around 10 or more things, the only way i know how to go about doing this is many IF statements together:

```
IF(statement>value,IF(statement>value,IF............))) as an example
```

is there an easier and simple way of doing this? all these nested IF statements are hard to keep up and hard on the eyes after a while, also i would like to have the sum of the numbers after it goes pass these fitlers. please help

Comment: Are you using many conditions in one if?

Answer (score 0):

To get the proper format for a SUM formula with 3 conditional IF statements. Is it this?

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$20=A25,IF($B$1:$B$20=B25,IF($C$1:$C$20=C25))),$D$1:$D$20)
```

Your can try this code:

```
=IF(SUM($A$1:$A$20)=A25,IF(SUM($B$1:$B$20)=B25,IF(SUM($C$1:$C$20)=C25,SUM($D$1:$D$20),0),0),0)
```

[**NESTED IF**](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php)